# Removing spheres

Tags: java, java-3d

I have finnaly managed to make my program detect collision between two balls that I have created in Java-3D; the player ball and the enemy ball. Now the problem is that I don't know how to make the player ball be removed when it collides with the enemy ball. I have tried some simple stuffs like `objTrans.removeChild(sphere);` and `objRoot.removeChild(objTrans);` (objTrans is my TransformGroup and objRoot is my BranchGroup), in both cases I get this error message

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.media.j3d.RestrictedAccessException: Group: only a BranchGroup node may be removed
```

I also tried `objRoot.detach();` but then I get the error message:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.media.j3d.CapabilityNotSetException: BranchGroup: no capability to detach
```

I don't know any other ways to make the ball be removed. Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem when designing a game myself. The solution that I found worked best was to store the objects that could possibly be destroyed in a list which I could iterate over and delete elements whenever necessary.

Comment: How would I do that with spheres in java-3d?

Comment: Well before you get to making a List make sure you are using a BranchGroup object. Because only these can be removed from live scenes by using branch.detach()

Comment: When I do that I get a error message saying                                  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.media.j3d.CapabilityNotSetException: BranchGroup: no capability to detach

Answer (score 0):

A simple code example. Each time you call updateModel (), a BranchGroup is removed, it is then updated with the new shape, and then added again

```
private BranchGroup             mapGroup = null;

public void updateModel (....)
{
    Shape3D                 shape;

    // Update 3D primitives
    if (mapGroup != null)                       // remove previous 3D model
        object.removeChild (mapGroup);      

    shape = facesTexturedShape (....);
    if (shape != null)                          // add new 3D model if non-null
    {
        mapGroup = new BranchGroup ();
        mapGroup.setCapability (BranchGroup.ALLOW_DETACH);
        mapGroup.addChild (shape);

        object.addChild (mapGroup);         
    }
}
```